# Blue Jack Audio Line In Playback Volume control

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I'm on Windows 10. I want to be able to control the "playback volume" of the blue audio line in jack (don't know how it's called correctly sorry) without having to open up Realtek HD Audio Manager every time.

[image]

Would be great if I could do that in the system tray, like with AudioSwitch, a program I use that lets me control the volume of my output devices

[image]

Does anyone know a program that could do that or has another solution for me? I don't even think it's that hard to program, it would just take me A LOT of time to figure everything out, I guess?